# How can i get template's type if my instance is stl map?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want a get_value template function.

please see the following code:

```
template<typename T>
(something i want) get_value(const T& m, int key) {
  auto it = m.upper_bound(key);
  return it == m.begin() ? (*it).second : (*--it).second;  // please notice here,
  // if my instance is map<int, map<string, int>> the return type should be m.second's type
  // that's map<string, int>
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>> m;
  auto& it = get_value(m, 10);
}
```

as you can see, the template function should have a return type, which is depend on instance's second type, is there any method i can get this type to make the code runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "second type" in a [`std::map<K,V>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is called `std::map<K,V>::mapped_type`. However, you can use `auto` to let the compiler deduce that for you:

```
template<typename T>
auto get_value(const T& m, int key) {
  auto it = m.upper_bound(key);
  return it == m.begin() ? (*it).second : (*--it).second;  // please notice here,
}
```

or with explicit type:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::mapped_type get_value(const T& m, int key) {
  auto it = m.upper_bound(key);
  return it == m.begin() ? (*it).second : (*--it).second;  // please notice here,
}
```

Comment: @nick as Stepan correctly notes, you have to consider what to actually return (reference vs copy). I simply assumed you want to return a copy

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++14 standard or above, the safest way to go would be to use `decltype(auto)` as the return type:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) get_value(const T& m, int key);
```

The difference to a plain `auto` is that `decltype(auto)` preserves cv-qualifiers, and in your case you most likely want to forward exactly the same type that `std::map` gives you.

For example, since the actual code uses `std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>>`, you might want to avoid copying the return value every time, and `decltype(auto)` will achieve that.

Comment: for some reasons, i just can use c++11, can decltype(T::mapped_type) work?

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is a special language construct that does forwarding of the exact type. If C++14 is not available, returning just `auto` (or `const auto&` to avoid copy) would also not work. Then if you want to avoid copying return value, I suggest changing return type to `const typename std::map<K, V>::mapped_type&`.